# how to handle empty results in KQL query?

Tags: azure, kql

trying to write KQL query counting resources in Azure subscriptions. I'm having problem with subs with no resources since nothing is return. so i want to merge [left] all subscription with [right] all resources:

```
$queryAllOuter = "resourceContainers 
    | where type =~ 'microsoft.resources/subscriptions'
    | project subscriptionId, subName=name
    | join kind=leftouter resources on subscriptionId
    | summarize nrOfResources=count() by subscriptionId,subName
    | sort by nrOfResources asc"
```

the problem is that empty subs are summarized as having 1 resource. when i checked the records before summarize, such empty record looks like that:

subscriptionId   : xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx
subName          : Visual Studio Professional Subscription
subscriptionId1  :
name             :
id               :
type             :
tenantId         :
kind             :
location         :
resourceGroup    :
managedBy        :
sku              :
plan             :
properties       :
tags             :
identity         :
zones            :
extendedLocation :
ResourceId       :

how to produce some output on null returns?

tried different combinations of using iff, isnull, extend - but it's IMHO deeper issue ... no idea how to approach it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My preferred way would be to first count and then join.

```
resourceContainers 
| where type =~ 'microsoft.resources/subscriptions'
| project subscriptionId, subName=name
| join kind=leftouter 
  (
    resources
    | summarize nrOfResources = count() by subscriptionId
  ) on subscriptionId
| extend nrOfResources = coalesce(nrOfResources, 0)
| sort by nrOfResources asc
```

You can also join and then count those rows where the subscriptionId from the right side is not empty.

```
resourceContainers 
| where type =~ 'microsoft.resources/subscriptions'
| project subscriptionId, subName=name
| join kind=leftouter resources on subscriptionId
| summarize nrOfResources=countif(isnotempty(subscriptionId1)) by subscriptionId,subName
| sort by nrOfResources asc
```

Comment: impressive. i tried something very close to the second one, but got the error that i can't use right size on summary as it doesn't exist... or something like that. 
both solutions work. thank you!